# Password manager in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, passwords, android-webview

How to get **UserName(Email)** and **password** from the website after successful logged In to `store local database` with the domain name and auto-fill username and password when open the same website.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we are loading wesite url in a WebView and not using the native android's Input Field controls.

So, With the Android Webview, We can't access the Input Field data. (UserName and Password)

Comment: But Firefox , Chrome many of the browser are working great at this type of problem.

Comment: No Its the logic from web (backend). InputFeield in Firefox is accessed in Web platform and not in native android webview. In Android we must need to make our custom layout to do so.